# Django render templates from seperate app's in one template file

Tags: django, templates, view

I need to display content of two templates (from different views) on 1 webpage (these are login and registration form side by side, sooner or later i will include other apps).

So I created index.html for displaying both templates - login.html and register.html - by usage of {% include %} templatetag. However, when it came to validation of registration form after i typed incorrect values i got redirected to template that I've imported.

How I can solve my issue of having forms from two completely seperate views in other (third) template?

Comment: A request cannot be handled by two views at the same time. I think your approach is wrong. Post your code so that people may guide you

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WMfnfDp6
Thats my code, please review it :)

Answer (score 0):

> How I can solve my issue of having forms from two completely seperate
>   views in other (third) template?

You should specify the action attribute of your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a context variable (for example 'type') to distinguish between the two forms in same template.

In view1:

```
if login_form.is_valid():
    # do something
    return render_to_response("home.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    return render_to_response("index.html", {"login_form": login_form, "type": "login"}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In view2:

```
if register_form.is_valid:
    # do something
    return render_to_response("home.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    return render_to_response("index.html", {"register_form": register_form, "type": "register"}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks for some info. Thats my code for a little review :)
http://pastebin.com/WMfnfDp6